# Tuba technique using chords in Dixieland

Tags: technique, performing, tuba

When one has lost their place in a tune, how can one play a non-specific note sound on the tuba to replace an actual note – to keep the rhythm/tempo going until they find where they are?

I have searched for information on this idea, but was unable to find anything.

Comment: I'm intrigued - what's the musical context?

Comment: I would work something out with someone in your ensemble, so they can help you find your place.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS - From the title, it sounds like the context is Dixieland.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly make sure you have a mouthpiece extractor available and only then...
slap the mouthpiece with the palm of your right hand.

Comment: That's how I used to determine the base note on my trumpet!